# how to create a concatened variable from many variables in sas

Tags: sas, concatenation

I have many variables (about 100), and most of the variable value is missing. i want to concatenate all the 104 variables' values to create a new variable for each record. Are there any easy way to do this without type in the 104 variable name?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the variable name shortcuts with the `CAT` family of functions.  You don't provide much information on your variables, so there are a few different choices depending on details like character/numeric, what you want missing to show up as, etc.; but here's the simple answer.

```
data want;
set have;
totalvar = cats(of var1--var104);
run;
```

`OPTIONS MISSING=' ';` might be helpful to make numeric missings turn into spaces.  If you have an array for your variables, you can use `cats(of yourarray[*])` as a shortcut.